# Kendo UI condition in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, kendo-ui

In the template I want the 30 to be bold and blue. And the rest of template text not blue or bold.

```
          labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    margin: {
                        left: 55
                    },
                    color: "#1246BB",
                    format: "{0}",
                    template: "#= value # \n <b>30</b>"
                },
```

edit: here is a plunker http://dojo.telerik.com/IzAcURaD/16

Answer (score 2):

If you have a condition in your code, use an `if` statement:

```
template: "# if (value == 30) { #<strong>#= value #</strong># } else { ##=value## } #"
```

The above template is printing `<strong>30</strong>` in case `value == 30` or just the value otherwise.

Useful references:

- https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview
- https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/templates/index

**UPDATE**

The chart label's template isn't a common template. It output is rendered in a [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) tag, which can't handle html tags. So I found a property called [`series.label.visual`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.labels.visual) where you can format that output properly:

```
labels: {
    font:"10px tahoma;", // I removed the 'bold' style from the default font
    visual: function(e) {
      // createVisual() method returns the default style to be used as a base style
      var visual = e.createVisual();

      // Some checkings
      if (e.text && Number(e.text) == 70 && visual.children) {
        // The 'visual' object returned from createVisual() has an array of child items. 
        // Below we are iterating through it to change the desired values
        visual.children.forEach(child => {
          if (child.options) {
            // Now we add the bold style to the font
            child.options.font = "bold 10px tahoma;";
          }
        });
      }

      // Return the updated visual styles
      return visual;
    }
},
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/AdadaCOD)

Comment: For some reason this works in the tool tip but not in the labels property in series. I get the text <b> ...</b> still

Comment: I added a plunker to show you what I am talking about. look at the valule with 70

Comment: @GeorgeXia yeah I see what you mean. It turns out that it is not a common template, the template output is added to a `<text>` tag, which can't handle html tags.. I'm searching for a solution.